# How to Migrate data from multiple T-SQL Queries to Single Table?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I want to enter data from mutiple T-SQL queries into my azure sql database, We want to enter data in such a way so that we have 8 columns in a single table in azure sql database, and for those 8 columns we have multiple T-SQL statements that 1 for each that will enter the data from the select statments into the azure sql database, how can this be achieved, for long term we want this to run as a job going forward.

Answer (score 0):

If your multiple T-SQL queries run in one database, I suggest you can think about the Azure Data Factory.

Azure Data Factory can help migrate data from one table or multiple tables to Azure SQL database by T-SQL queries.

You also can  trigger the pipeline runs on a schedule. You can create a scheduler trigger to schedule the pipeline to run periodically (hourly, daily, and so on).

For details about Data factory, please see [Azure Data Factory Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/).

Tutorials:

1. [Incrementally load data from multiple tables in SQL Server to an Azure SQL database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-incremental-copy-multiple-tables-portal#review-the-results)
2. [Copy multiple tables in bulk by using Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-bulk-copy-portal).

And if your source data is in SQL Server instance, you can create a linked server to Azure SQL Database, this also can help you achieve that.
You can query and insert data to linked Azure SQL server by T-SQL statements.

About SQL Server linked server, please see: [Create Linked Servers (SQL Server Database Engine)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/create-linked-servers-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017)

Hope this helps.